# Viewing Documents like PDF,DOCX,RTF files in Android

Tags: android, pdf, document, rtf, docx

Is there any opensource sdk which helps to display or render documents {PDF, docx, rtf,doc} files within my android application, without navigating to third party apps. There are tons of question out there both old and new ,most of them pointing towards the priced versions like

[Artifex smart office](http://smartoffice.artifex.com/) for viewing documents

[Aspose](https://github.com/asposewords/Aspose_Words_Android) for converting file formats

Are there any opensource libs which can be used for this purpose. please guide.
Some say port Apache POI or Docx4j i dont understand how to do it.

If it was for pdf only i would opt [PDF viewer](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library). But what about other document types like docx and rtf.

Comment: Found a solution yet????

Comment: @RonakKhandelwal : There is almost no free SDK out there which does all three for you. What i did was bought an aspose license and converted other formats to PDF and rendered using PDF viewer.

Comment: But since they are the user files I am not keeping or storing the files in any format so wouldn't it affect the efficiency? I mean wouldn't it take more time?

Comment: @RonakKhandelwal My requirement like user can download a file from server and view it. The files were uploaded from a web portal. Server itself keeps PDF format files for downloading in app. So i had not much problem . Your requirement might vary.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas what are the fie formats you are able to convert to pdf.

Comment: @vickyVick finally bought a Aspose license and converted different file formats to PDF in server and used PDFViewer in android application to display them

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Thanks for your comment. Can you suggest me any other unpaid third party or other way for the same.

Comment: I didn't find any open source sdk at that time which provided flawless performance you can try and research in android arsenal..

Comment: @GeorgeThomas All is wain. There is no open source and concrete sdk for the same.